# biblatex. supress \bibstring if two curly braces are used

Tags: biblatex

I have a `mvreference` with the field `volumes`. Its format is declared by biblatex as
`\DeclareFieldFormat{volumes}{#1~\bibstring{volumes}}`.

How can I force biblatex to *not* use the `\bibstring`-command if the entry is wrapped in **two curly braces**, like in the case of the MWE, but use it, if there it is only wrapped in **one**?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@mvreference{mylexA,
    shorthand       = {mylex},
    title           = {Lexikon in mehreren Bänden},
    volumes         = {{Lexikon in 20 Bänden in zwei Teilen. Zwei Supplement-Bde. mit Anh.}},
    editor          = {Some One},
    location        = {München},
    year            = {1997-2001}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

Welcome.
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: If this is not possible, other solutions are welcome, too!

Comment: I think checking for double braces is quite hard, but `\DeclareFieldFormat{volumes}{\ifnumerals{#1}{#1~\bibstring{volumes}}{#1}}` gives quite a pleasant output in your case. If I read the documentation correctly, `volumes` is only ever supposed to hold the number of volumes, so it will almost always contain a simple number like `5` and in some cases a more convoluted text like in your MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no built-in function to check for double curly braces in a field. But that should hardly ever be necessary. 
Often it is more interesting to ask whether a field contains a number/numeral or text.

This seems to be the case with your example as well. Normally the `volumes` field just contains the bare number of volumes that belong to a `maintitle` (or `title`) (see p. 23 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), and the examples in `biblatex-examples.bib`). In these cases it appears quite natural to add the `volumes` bibstring. Sometimes one might have to add some more explanatory text like "22-volume Encyclopaedia in two parts", then of course the `volumes` bibstring is looks out of place.

So it seems much more natural to check whether the field `volumes` contains numbers or text.
If it contains text it is hardly appropriate to add the `volumes` bibstring.
Even if it might fit in a situation like "Encyclopedia consisting of 22" "volumes" (with "volumes" added via by `\bibstring{volumes}`), it will look massively weird if you change your language settings to, say, German and get "Encyclopedia consisting of 22 Bände".

See the advice given regarding the `edition` field (p. 16 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), and the examples in `biblatex-examples.bib`):

> The edition of a printed publication. This must be an integer, not an
>   ordinal. Don’t say `edition={First}` or `edition={1st}` but `edition={1}`.
>   The bibliography style converts this to a language dependent ordinal.
>   It is also possible to give the edition as a literal string, for
>   example “Third, revised and expanded edition”.

So we can make `volumes` behave like `edition` in that respect via

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{volumes}{%
  \ifnumerals{#1}
    {#1~\bibstring{volumes}}
    {#1}}
```